# How to Run an exe from windows service and stop service when the exe process quits?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

I am a complete beginner to working with windows services.  I have a basic skeleton worked out for the service and I am currently doing this:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        base.OnStart(args);
        Process.Start(@"someProcess.exe");
    }
```

just to fire-off the exe at the start of the program.

However, I'd like to have the service stop itself when the process started from the exe quits.
I'm pretty sure I need to do some sort of threading (something I am also a beginner with), but I'm not sure of the overall outline of how this works, nor the specific way to stop a process from within itself.
Could you help me with the general process for this (i.e. start a thread from OnStart, then what...?)? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.COMPONENTMODEL.BACKGROUNDWORKER);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true) for the threading, use [`Process.WaitForExit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.DIAGNOSTICS.PROCESS.WAITFOREXIT);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION%3dV4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true) to wait for the process to terminate until you stop your service.

You're right that you should do some threading, doing lots of work in the `OnStart` may render errors about not starting correctly from Windows when starting the service.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{

    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("file.exe");
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
    base.Stop();
}
```

**Edit**
You may also want to move the `Process p` to a class member and stop the process in the `OnStop` to make sure that you can stop the service again if the exe goes haywire.

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
    p.Kill();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a `ServiceController` to do it, it has a [Stop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.stop.aspx) method. Make sure your service has the [CanStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.canstop.aspx) property set to true.

Answer (score 1):

`someProcess.exe` should have **someLogic** to stop the calling service ;)

Use the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.stop.aspx) class.

```
// Toggle the Telnet service - 
// If it is started (running, paused, etc), stop the service.
// If it is stopped, start the service.
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("Telnet");
Console.WriteLine("The Telnet service status is currently set to {0}", 
                  sc.Status.ToString());

if  ((sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)) ||
     (sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)))
{
   // Start the service if the current status is stopped.

   Console.WriteLine("Starting the Telnet service...");
   sc.Start();
}  
else
{
   // Stop the service if its status is not set to "Stopped".

   Console.WriteLine("Stopping the Telnet service...");
   sc.Stop();
}  

// Refresh and display the current service status.
sc.Refresh();
Console.WriteLine("The Telnet service status is now set to {0}.", 
                   sc.Status.ToString());
```

Code is from the page linked above.

Comment: Thanks, this does look like it would accomplish the end result - if I am developing the exe aswell. Isn't this more of a workaround than a solution, though? And it would only work assuming I'm writing the .exe. Assume I don't have access to the source for the exe, and this should still be do-able through the windows service itself.