# Simulate CTRL-C to shutdown Java application on C#

Tags: c#, java, shutdown-hook

I founded some code to correctly shutdown java application from C# console application,  using `InputSimulator` but when i tried it, it didnt give me an expected result.

**When i close my java application using keyboard CTRL-C**

```
...
[INFO] 2012-07-03 19:29:36 - Packet: [C] 0x02
[INFO] 2012-07-03 19:29:40 - Shutdown hook raised, shutting down...
[INFO] 2012-07-03 19:29:45 - All data saved. Good luck!
```

**When i close my java application using InputSimulator**

> Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.6-b01 mixed mode):
>
> "DestroyJavaVM" prio=6 tid=0x4b524000 nid=0x6f4 waiting on condition
>   [0x00000000 ]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> "Thread-1" prio=6 tid=0x4b523800 nid=0x65c waiting on condition
>   [0x4cd0f000]    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
>           at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
>           at gameserver.utils.DeadlockDetector.run(DeadlockDetector.java:76)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> "server-rdc-acceptor" prio=6 tid=0x4b523000 nid=0x102c runnable
>   [0x4cc7f000]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>           at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
>           at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(Unknown Source)
>
> ```
>     at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(Unknown Source)
>     - locked <0x3e057ef0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
>     - locked <0x3e057ee0> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
>     - locked <0x3e057cc0> (a sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl)
>     at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(Unknown Source)
>     at commons.ngen.network.Acceptor.run(Acceptor.java:259)
> ```

**My InputSimulator using:**

```
private void StartServer()
{

                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                info.UseShellExecute = false;
                info.FileName = "java"
                info.Arguments = "-Xms512m -Xmx1024m server.jar gameserver.Server"
                ServerProcess = new Process();
                ServerProcess.StartInfo = info;
                ServerProcess.Start();

                Thread.Sleep(60000);
                CloseCorrectly(ServerProcess);
}

private void CloseCorrectly(Process pr)
{
  IntPtr hWnd = pr.MainWindowHandle;
  if (hWnd != null)
            {
                    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    InputSimulator f = new InputSimulator();

                    f.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.CANCEL);

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
}
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `ServerProcess.StandardInput.Close()`? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283128/how-do-i-send-ctrlc-to-a-process-in-c) question.

Comment: Also try just sending the VirtualKeyCode.CANCEL without the CONTROL modifier. I think CANCEL actually encapsulates the entire "ctrl-c" command.

Comment: This might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741820/start-a-exe-file-from-a-service-and-stop-it-by-sending-sigbreak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The homepage (http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) suggests that ctrl-C qould be done via:

```
InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_C);
```

The docs don't suggest what cancel is but fortunately JamesB has bravely searched the source to find that it refers to break.

Try the above code and that should hopefully simulate a real ctrl-c.

Comment: From the source cancel is 0x03 and from msdn msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731(VS.85).aspx it seems this refers to Break

Comment: @JamesB: Cool. Thanks for checking. I'll update my answer to be more definite about that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are already using InputSimulator and the question is for SimulateModifiedKeyStroke

But you can achieve this by calling

```
Sendkeys.SendWait("^c")
```